# pandas calculate summary DataFrame for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a file with a various products, locations, Licence_ends and I need to count how many products are running out of licence by date and how many are available to reorder in that quarter, the sample data below:

```
   Item    Store    Category    Licence_ends    Available_to_reorder
0  A01929  North    Office      2018 Q1         Yes
1  A02911  South    Windows     2019 Q3         Yes
2  B11282  North    Adobe       2019 Q2         No
3  C73162  East     Office      2018 Q4         Yes
4  A12817  West     Windows     2020 Q1         No
```

What I want to achieve would look like this:

```
   Store    Category    2018 Q1 2018 Q2 ... 2020 Q4
0  East     Windows       0       1           24   # cumulative sum of previous quarters
1  East     Office        1       2           11
2  East     Adobe         1       4           6
3  West     Windows       2       2           18
4  West     Office        0       0           0
...
11 South    Adobe         1       0           12
12 Total    All       col.sum()  col.sum()   col.sum()
```

I started with the below code, but I got lost and don't know the proper way to do it:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

file = r'C:\Users\G01024822\Desktop\products.xlsx'
sheet = r'store_data'
data = pd.read_excel(file,sheetname=sheet,na_values='')
quarters = ['2018 Q1','2018 Q2','2018 Q3','2018 Q4','2019 Q1','2019 Q2','2019 Q3','2019 Q4','2020 Q1','2020 Q2','2020 Q3','2020 Q4']
categories = ['Windows','Office','Adobe']
stores = data['store'].unique().tolist()

mydata = {}
plandata = {}

for store in stores:
    transaction = data[data['Store']==store]

    for category in categories:
        frame = transaction[transaction['Category']==category]
        cycle = {}
        if frame.shape[0] != 0:
            for quarter in quarters:
                temp = frame[frame['License_ends']==quarter]
                out_of_licence = temp['Item'].count()
                cycle[quarter] = out_of_licence



        else:
            pass

        mydata[category] = cycle
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydata,orient='index')

df
```

this is what I'm producing, but just for the last store only:

[image]

for each category respectively. I tried adding lists, series, dictionaries to empty dataframes, I tried append, add, assign, and didn't get what I want. Could you please point me into right direction here?

I went through most methods here in SO and also looked in Wes Kinley book @ Safari Books, but just cannot land it. Please help. I have to do it by Monday and I'm absolutely nowhere.

Comment: Did you try `dataframe.groupby`? i don't have an immediate answer, but it looks like a job for `groupby`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with a conditional logic sum using `lambda` in the *aggfunc* argument. Below demonstrates with random data, seeded for reproducibility, of course adding the *Open Source* category.

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(22)
LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["".join(list(np.random.choice(LETTERS,1)) +
                                    [str(np.random.randint(1000, 9000))]) for _ in range(500)],
                   'Store': [np.random.choice(['North', 'South', 
                                               'East', 'West'],1).item(0) for _ in range(500)],
                   'Category': [np.random.choice(['Office', 'Windows', 
                                                  'Adobe', 'Open Source'],1).item(0) for _ in range(500)],
                   'Licence_ends': ["Q".join([str(np.random.randint(2018, 2021))] +
                                             [str(np.random.randint(1,4))]) for _ in range(500)],
                   'Available_to_reorder': [np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'],1).item(0) for _ in range(500)]},
                  columns = ['Item', 'Store', 'Category', 'Licence_ends', 'Available_to_reorder'])

print(df.head())
#     Item  Store     Category Licence_ends Available_to_reorder
# 0  V7276   West  Open Source       2018Q2                  Yes
# 1  M8104   West      Windows       2020Q1                   No
# 2  E6478  North  Open Source       2019Q2                   No
# 3  W5587  South  Open Source       2018Q2                  Yes
# 4  U3952  South      Windows       2019Q3                   No
# 5  E1989   East       Office       2018Q1                   No
# 6  S6646   West      Windows       2019Q2                  Yes
# 7  N7616   West        Adobe       2019Q1                  Yes
# 8  H6410   East        Adobe       2020Q2                   No
# 9  J8176   West       Office       2020Q1                  Yes
```

**Pivot Table** *(results as a multindex dataframe)*

```
pvt_df = df.pivot_table(index=['Store', 'Category'], columns='Licence_ends', values='Available_to_reorder', 
                        aggfunc = lambda x: sum(x=='Yes'), margins=True, margins_name='Total')

print(pvt_df)                                                            
# Licence_ends       2018Q1  2018Q2  2018Q3  2019Q1  2019Q2  2019Q3  2020Q1  2020Q2  2020Q3  Total
# Store Category                                                                                  
# East  Adobe           3.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     3.0     2.0     1.0     4.0     0.0     14
#       Office          1.0     3.0     4.0     2.0     NaN     4.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     17
#       Open Source     1.0     4.0     2.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     1.0     2.0     1.0     12
#       Windows         1.0     2.0     3.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     1.0     3.0     1.0     13
# North Adobe           3.0     4.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     3.0     0.0     2.0     16
#       Office          1.0     0.0     3.0     0.0     1.0     2.0     3.0     0.0     0.0     10
#       Open Source     3.0     1.0     0.0     1.0     1.0     2.0     2.0     1.0     2.0     13
#       Windows         2.0     2.0     5.0     0.0     2.0     2.0     1.0     1.0     3.0     18
# South Adobe           2.0     3.0     NaN     2.0     2.0     3.0     1.0     3.0     2.0     18
#       Office          4.0     3.0     1.0     2.0     NaN     2.0     3.0     2.0     2.0     19
#       Open Source     1.0     2.0     2.0     4.0     1.0     NaN     NaN     3.0     2.0     15
#       Windows         2.0     1.0     1.0     2.0     2.0     2.0     1.0     3.0     1.0     15
# West  Adobe           1.0     1.0     0.0     4.0     3.0     3.0     1.0     0.0     3.0     16
#       Office          1.0     1.0     3.0     3.0     3.0     2.0     2.0     2.0     1.0     18
#       Open Source     4.0     2.0     4.0     0.0     0.0     4.0     1.0     1.0     2.0     18
#       Windows         2.0     2.0     1.0     5.0     4.0     1.0     4.0     1.0     0.0     20
# Total                32.0    31.0    31.0    27.0    25.0    30.0    26.0    27.0    23.0    252
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.